# Floating Action Menu not working with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, floating-action-button

I have a Floating Action Menu (JQuery + CSS) :

HTML :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div id="hamburger" class="waves-effect waves-light">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <span class="icon-bar" id="one"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar" id="two"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar" id="thr"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="btnExit" class="hamburger-nav">
    <span class="floatingmenu_label">Exit</span>
    <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/pencil-128.png">
  </div>
  <div id="btnUsers" class="hamburger-nav">
    <span class="floatingmenu_label">Users</span>
     <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/pencil-128.png">
  </div>
  <div id="btnJobs" class="hamburger-nav">
    <div class="floatingmenu_label">Jobs</div>
     <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/pencil-128.png">
  </div>
  <div id="btnFilters" class="hamburger-nav">
    <span class="floatingmenu_label">Filters</span>
     <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/pencil-128.png">
  </div>
  <div id="btnReports" class="hamburger-nav">
    <span class="floatingmenu_label">Reports</span>
     <img style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" src="https://www.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/pencil-128.png">
  </div>
```

Javascript / JQuery :

```
  $('#hamburger').click(function() {
    $('#hamburger').toggleClass('show');
    $('.hamburger-nav').toggleClass('show');
  });
```

CSS :

```
.floatingmenu_label {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -160px;
  color: #454545;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#btnExit.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-125%);
  transform: translateY(-125%);
}

#btnUsers.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-250%);
  transform: translateY(-250%);
}

#btnJobs.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-375%);
  transform: translateY(-375%);
}

#btnReports.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-500%);
  transform: translateY(-500%);
}

#btnFilters.show {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-625%);
  transform: translateY(-625%);
}

#hamburger {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: 5%;
  background-color: #FF5722;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#hamburger .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.hamburger-nav {
  z-index: 9;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10.5%;
  right: 5.5%;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibilty: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#hamburger.show {
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
}

#hamburger.show #wrapper {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

#hamburger.show #one {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotateZ(45deg) scaleX(0.9);
  transform: translateY(6px) rotateZ(45deg) scaleX(0.9);
}

#hamburger.show #two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburger.show #thr {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(-45deg) scaleX(0.9);
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotateZ(-45deg) scaleX(0.9);
}

.hamburger-nav.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This works fine so far.

But when I add the bootstrap.css css it gets messed up.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Here's a fiddle, but it works buggy right now. To make it work correctly just remove the bootstrap.min.css on the left :  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs2a8fe1/)

can anybody help me with making this work while having the bootstrap.css included at the same time ?

Thanks in advance !

working :
[image]

Not working :[image]

EDIT : finally found the culprit :

in bootstrap.css there's this class :

```
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

that overrode my class. I simply renamed my class and everything worked fine again.
In Chrome, right-click element (button) -> inspect element -> styles tab shows every class that affects the selected element. Very useful !

Comment: I fixed the problem by replacing the bootstrap.css file with a newer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is always good practice to code custom CSS above the Bootstrap CSS.

There are a couple of ways you can fix this, either purely by CSS or adding  some HTML wrappers then applying CSS. I will give you the pure CSS solution.

To center a child element relative to a parent element, use

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

If you apply this to `.hamburger-menu > img` and `#hamburger > #wrapper`, you will end up with what you want to achieve.

**Edit**: Same case with the text labels, except you only want to transform on the Y axis and not the X axis.

Comment: I fixed the problem by replacing the bootstrap.css file with a newer one. But I accept your answer as the correct one, because it's much saver coding it your way.